# Sorting and grouping a mutlidimensional array in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, grouping

I need some help with sorting a multidimensional array in php. I need the array to be grouped into months, and then sorted by month. Here's my original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 5
            [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2011
            [Month] => 08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 7
            [EventName] => Copy of Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2011
            [Month] => 07
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 1
            [EventName] => Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2011
            [Month] => 05
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [IdEvent] => 6
            [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
            [Year] => 2011
            [Month] => 05
        )

)
```

And here's what I'm hoping to get:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [IdEvent] => 1
                [EventName] => Opening snow weekend
                [Year] => 2011
                [Month] => 05
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [IdEvent] => 6
                [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                [Year] => 2011
                [Month] => 05
            )

    )

    [1] => Array (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [IdEvent] => 7
                [EventName] => Copy of Copy of Opening snow weekend
                [Year] => 2011
                [Month] => 07
            )

    )

    [2] => Array (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [IdEvent] => 5
                [EventName] => Copy of Opening snow weekend
                [Year] => 2011
                [Month] => 08
            )
    )

)
```

Comment: What is the logic of your sorting? Maybe I'm missing something but I cannot see what it is you are sorting on.

Comment: @stefgosselin: Sort it by Year / Month / Day is what appears to be the pattern.

Comment: Ok, I think this is by month .. all events for a given month in their own array?

Comment: Yep I'm trying to group them by "Month"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an easily sortable key for each month-container, then just use ksort

```
$months = array();
foreach ($input_array AS $arr) {
  $months[$arr['Month']][] = $arr;
}
ksort($months);
```

if you want, you can then use `array_values` to turn it into a standard integer-key array

Comment: You did not consider the year, would not work when the array has key with different years.

Comment: I'm not using 'Year' at the moment, it's only pulling the current year from the database to make the first array, should have left that out when I posted it here :)

Comment: I went for something  that takes the year into account. But hey if this works for you so much the better ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, just maybe something like this:

```
$sortedArray = array();

foreach ($unsortedArray as $key => $row) {
  $month[$key] = $row['month'];
  $year[$key]  = $row['year'];
}

$sortedArray =  array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $month, SORT_ASC, $unsortedArray);
```

- Totally untried, untested, exprerimental *and* from the top of my head.
- You may need SORT_NUMERIC instead of SORT_ASC, I ain't sure.